# Distribute words along circle without distortion

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a list of words that I would like to be distributed along a circle, with the words reading from the center out, like the image below.

[image]

This is almost what I want, but the words are distorted (the lettering gets larger the further it is from the center). Is there a way to do this without having the words distorted?

Comment: What have you tried? Post your tests and tell us how you got there and what didn't work! It's unclear if the image you posted is something you did or not.

Comment: I tried converting the words to a bush and then applying it to a circle, that's how I have the image above.

Answer (score 1):

1. Type a word
2. Rotate it, (alt click where you want center to be)
3. Hit <kbd>ctl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> untill you have done a full circle

Answer (score -1):

I think you must type your text in LaTeX an use some packages and then import .ps file in Illustrator(if your text editing is important for you!).